# $rk(x\times y)$ and $rk(x^{y})$?

Tags: set-theory

My working ground is $ZF^{-}$, i.e $ZF$ without the Axiom of Foundation.

1. I define $V_{0}:=0$, $V_{\alpha +1}:=\mathcal P(V_{\alpha})$ and, if $\lambda$ is limit, $V_{\lambda}:=\bigcup_{\beta <\lambda} V_{\beta}$. I put $WF:=\bigcup_{\alpha\in ON} V_{\alpha}$, where $ON$ is the class of all ordinals, and call $WF$ the class of well-founded sets.
2. For a set $x\in WF$, the rank of $x$, $rk(x)$, is the least ordinal such that $x\subseteq V_{\alpha}$ or equivalently the least ordinal such that $x\in V_{\alpha +1}$.
3. Given $x,y\in WF$ I know that $z\in x\implies z\in WF\ \land\ rk(z)<rk(x)$ and that $rk(x)=\sup\{rk(z)+1:\ z\in x\}$. I also know that $\cup x,\ \mathcal{P}(x),\ \{x\},\ \{x,y\},\ x\cup y$ and $(x,y)$ are all elements of $WF$ and I computed their rank explicitly in terms of $rk(x),\ rk(y)$

Now I need to compute also $rk(x\times y)$ and $rk (x^{y})$ in terms of $rk(x)$ and $rk(y)$, where $x^{y}$ is the set of all functions $y\rightarrow x$ (I already know that $x\times y,\ x^{y}\in WF$, for example since $x\times y\subseteq \mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}(x\cup y)$ and $x^{y}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(x\times y)$). For the first one, it was not difficult for me to see that
$$\max\{rk(x),rk(y)\}\leq rk(x\times y)\leq \max\{rk(x),rk(y)\} +2,$$
since $rk(x\times y)=\sup\{\max\{rk(a) ,\ rk(b)\} +3:\ (a,b)\in x\times y\}$. I can't go any further from this. I got similar bounds for $rk (x^{y})$ but nothing precise. Any help?

Comment: I assume you meant to say $x \in WF$ in point 2?

Comment: Hint: What is the rank of $\omega\times\omega$? What is the rank of $n\times n$? Can you show something about the case when $\mathrm{max}\{rk(x),rk(y)\}$ is a limit? What about when it is a successor ordinal?

Comment: @aws: yes, of course. For Apostolos, maybe I got it: if $A:=\max\{rk(x),rk(y)\}$ is limit, $A>\max\{rk(a)),rk(b)\} +3$ for each $(a,b)\in x\times y$, otherwise $A$ would be a successor ordinal (right?) and then $A=rk(x\times y)$. If $A=\gamma +1$ for some ordinal $\gamma$, suppose WLOG $A=rk(y)$. Since $A$ is successor there must be $b\in y$ such that $\gamma +1=rk(b)+1$ so that $rk(x\times y)=\sup\{\max\{rk(a) ,\ rk(b)\} +3:\ (a,b)\in x\times y\}=\sup\{(rk(b)+1)+2: b\in y\}=\max \{(rk(b)+1)+2:\ b\in y\}=A+2$. Is this right? Similar treatment for $x^{y}$?

Comment: @MarcoVergura: Yes it looks ok. For $x^y$ I think considering what this set is with respect to $x\times y$ may give a shorter solution (though I haven't really checked this one).